# How to retrieve all the rows in postgres where values of a jsonb key is greater then an int value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, syntax-error, jsonb

I'm new to postgres, so if this is newbie question, please redirect me. I'm trying to retrieve all the rows where the value is greater then 0.

This is my table `test`.

```
id | value
-----------
1  |  {'a':1, 'b':2}
2  |  {'a':0, 'b':2}
3  |  {'a':1, 'b':1}
4  |  {'a':0, 'b':0}
5  |  {'a':3, 'b':1}
6  |  {'a':0, 'b':2}
```

I have attempted

```
SELECT * FROM test where value --> 'a' > 0;
```

but this didn't work. I just got

```
ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type jsonb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--` denotes a comment, so everything after it is ignored. Your query is effectively:

```
SELECT * FROM test where value
```

Which makes the error you're getting quite clear. It seems you meant to use the `->>` operator to extract the element from the JSONB column. Note, however, it will return a text value, and you'd need to convert it to an int yourself:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE (value->>'a')::int > 0
```